# The sanitizer was unable to parse the following block of html: <style>body {display: none;}

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables, ngsanitize

Here I was fetching data from server and showing in data table.
Before that I am sanitizing the data but it gives this error for this input.  body {display: none;}

Error: [$sanitize:badparse] The sanitizer was unable to parse the following block of html: body {display: none;} http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$sanitize/badparse?p0=body%20%7Bdisplay%3A%20none%3B%7D

Sorry for any typos, get me out of this issue.

Comment: Share the block of code where you use `$sanitize` or a verifiable example.

Comment: angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                if (typeof value !== 'object' && typeof value !== 'Array') {
                  try {
                    data[key] = $sanitize(value);
                  } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                  }
                }
              });